# 'Object is possibly 'null'' error in React v18 with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, null

How to resolve the Object is possibly 'null' error in a React and Next.js application for the **visualViewport** property in TypeScript?

I have already defined a global definition augmentation file with the names `window.d.ts`, or `global.d.ts`, `visualViewport.d.ts`, tried playing with name to ensure and avoid naming problems and tried include this into `tsconfig.json`

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    visualViewport: VisualViewport;
  }
}
```

This issue arose after migrating to React v18, as the code that was previously valid in the form of `window.visualViewport.scale` now requires an additional check of `window.visualViewport && window.visualViewport.scale`.

Where exists articles with similar error so i tried most of them. However, the error still occurs, even though I know that the window object is defined. How can I fix this issue and avoid additional JavaScript checking?

Comment: Not really, just use modern JS syntax with "as" typing? `(window as any).(visualViewport as VisualViewport)?.scale`.

Comment: This is not a solution, in my project i have strict Typescript and don't use `any` or `as` casting only for exceptions. My provided solution `window.visualViewport && window.visualViewport.scale` in this case avoids that, but `visualViewport` is used a lot in the project so i want a global TS solution to avoid any workarounds and additional JS optional chaining cheking. As i mentioned in React v17 where was no issue

Comment: Even without `any` and `as`, the modern JS syntax `window.visualViewport?.scale` means you don't need `window.visualVieport && window.visualViewport.scale`. Use the [optional chaining syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to reference properties "if they exist".

Comment: For using optional chaining solution, TS is throwing `Object is possibly 'undefined'` error

Comment: on what, the `window` part? Because you can add an optional chain there too. `window?.visualViewport?.scale`, but declaring the window interface _should_ work? e.g. https://www.emmanuelgautier.com/blog/typescript-extend-window

Comment: window already is declared and has `visualViewport: Viewport | null` as this is an issue, i need to override `visualViewport` type to not have null part

Comment: But then you'd be lying in your typing, as visualViewport [can absolutely be null](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/cssom-view/#dom-window-visualviewport).